# Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 instead of -1009 in Swift service calls

Tags: ios, http, nsurlsession, url-parsing, nsurlerrordomain

Generally, while performing GET or POST calls in iOS using dataTaskWithRequest or sendAsynchronousRequest we use to face network related errors with error codes like,

- NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet = -1009
- NSURLErrorCannotConnectToHost = -1004
- NSURLErrorTimedOut = -1001

In my case i'm disconnecting the internet and performing service calls. So, the expected error code is **"NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet = -1009"**. But, its throwing **"NSURLErrorCannotConnectToHost = -1004"** like below,

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the 
server." UserInfo=0x1700f0e00 {NSUnderlyingError=0x170255e70 "The 
operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 
-1004.)", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://example.com/reg,   
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://example.com/reg, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, 
_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=51, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}
```

So, how to get the exact error status while using dataTaskWithRequest or sendAsynchronousRequest.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule, IIRC, the OS sends "not connected to Internet" only in two situations:

- The network is determined to be nonfunctional after:

  - One or more URL requests fail and
  - The OS tries to probe a well-known captive-portal-detection URL and
  - That request also fails
- No interface has an IP address

  - Including any connected VPNs
  - Excluding loopback interface

Up until the system reaches that state, the failures you see will be "cannot connect to host", because that's all the OS knows for certain.

As a rule, your app should interpret these in the same way — by using reachability to determine when to try again, then trying again when reachability changes.