# GameKit not working on watchOS 3

Tags: ios, swift, gamekit, watchos-3

I am trying to add GameKit support to my watchOS app. However, when running the app on a device the authentication fails with the error `NSURLErrorDomain code -1009 (null)`. When running in a simulator, the app fails to build saying it can't find the GameKit module.

How to fix these errors? I am using Xcode 8 + watchOS 3 and iOS 10.

EDIT: Code for the GameKit authentication helper class

```
import Foundation
import GameKit //ERROR: Can't find module when running in simulator
import WatchKit

let singleton = GameKitHelper()

class GameKitHelper {
    var gameCenterEnabled = false
    var points: Int64? = 0
    var rankings: [GKScore] = []
    let leaderboard = "LEAD_ID"
    var leaderboardRequest: GKLeaderboard?

    class var sharedInstance: GameKitHelper {
        return singleton
    }

    func authenticateLocalPlayer() {
        let player = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
        print("Authenticating local player")
        player.authenticateHandler = { error in
            if player.isAuthenticated {

                self.gameCenterEnabled = true
                DispatchQueue.main.async { () -> Void in
                    WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllers(withNames: ["View"], contexts: nil)
                }  
            } 
            else {
                self.gameCenterEnabled = false
                if error != nil {
                    print("GK Auth Error: \(error.debugDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On what line of code does the error occur? Can you edit your question to show where the compiler says the error comes from?

Comment: I found [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208917/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1004-instead-of-1009-in-swift-service-calls) which says that code -1009 means no internet connection.

Comment: Did you mamage yo get it working?

Comment: No, still not working. I have filed a bug report with Apple.

Comment: I have filled a bug aswell after trying with Beta 3.(OS10.1, WatchOS 3.1) 

Comment: I read the Xcode beta release notes:

Comment: GameKit framework is missing on simulator, at least they are aware of it

Comment: I'm updating to beta 3 right now, but it doesn't look like the problem will be fixed anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it works with WatchOS4 but not right away:

- Looks like you have to create a separate app with its own GameCenter leaderboard, then you can use GC groups for share the same data with the iOS companion.

Comment: Building using a device silences the warning, but the authentication fails. I'll try building a sample project and see if it works

Comment: I have try to add ATS into the plist, same results, 1009